# php set a cookie and change its value with auto actualisation

Tags: php, redirect, cookies, lang

Currently creating a small website, i'm trying to add a multi langage tool between french and english. But i'm facing some problems with it. Basically, I have two buttons, english and french to change langage. But if it's first visitor time, a default langage should be set (here, french).

So i created a small script, that doesnt work as i expect...

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['lang_ylx'])) {

 $timestamp_expiration = time()+30*24*3600 ;

if(!isset($_GET['lang'])) {                      
    setcookie('lang_ylx', 'fr',$timestamp_expiration, null, null, false, true);
}

else if ($_GET['lang']=='fr') {      // si la langue est 'fr' par le bouton de langue, on définit le cookie francais
    setcookie('lang_ylx', 'fr',$timestamp_expiration, null, null, false, true); //On définit un cookie de langue
    header('Location: index.php');  
} 

else if ($_GET['lang']=='en') { 
    setcookie('lang_ylx', 'en',$timestamp_expiration, null, null, false, true); 
    header('Location: index.php');  

}
```

That script is automatically loaded withind index.php with include. For now, I only have index.php and i'm trying, when I click for example english button, to pass a parameter in URL, then alter the cookie so it gets 'en' value, and then go back to index.php.

My lang files are two giant loop that test the value of the cookie.
But whenever I click english or french button, I'm stuck at lang.php, but it should go back to index.php, with new langage.

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$timestamp_expiration = time()+30*24*3600 ;
if(!isset($_COOKIE['lang_ylx'])) {
    //If you want your default to be english, use this:
    setcookie('lang_ylx', 'en', $timestamp_expiration, null, null, false, true);
    //French:
    setcookie('lang_ylx', 'fr',$timestamp_expiration, null, null, false, true);
}

/*if(!isset($_GET['lang'])) {                      
    setcookie('lang_ylx', 'fr',$timestamp_expiration, null, null, false, true);
}*/
//Comment out above because you're setting french every time llang isn't set.
if (isset($_GET['lang']){
    else if ($_GET['lang']=='fr') {      // si la langue est 'fr' par le bouton de langue, on définit le cookie francais
        setcookie("lang_ylx", "", time()-3600);
        setcookie('lang_ylx', 'fr',$timestamp_expiration, null, null, false, true); //On définit un cookie de langue
    header('Location: index.php');  
    } 

    else if ($_GET['lang']=='en') {
        setcookie("lang_ylx", "", time()-3600);
        setcookie('lang_ylx', 'en',$timestamp_expiration, null, null, false, true); 
        header('Location: index.php');  
    }
}
```

You had:

1. an } in the wrong place
2. not set any defaults

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesnt work. I get an error Undefined Index at those lignes :

    else if ($_GET['lang']=='fr') { 

and 

    else if ($_GET['lang']=='en') { 

So I tried to put those two inside an isset($_GET['lang'])) {

I dont get anymore errors, and I'm redirected to index.php, but it doesnt load english. When I click english button, it loads only french.

Then I tried to destroy existent cookies, but I saw that there were two ylx_lang cookies, one with fr and one with en. So I think I should destroy existent cookie to overwrite the new value, but I dont know how to do this

Comment: Doesnt work. I tried to delete all cookies in navigator, but it gives me a lot of errors, and is unable to load the content of variable, in which I put the text. First is lang.php loaded, then the variable file index-lang.php

Comment: Consider using SESSION instead of cookies.